# Convert negative number from String to unsigned Long

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to convert a negative number from String to unsigned long,however am getting an unexpected result due to "-" sign.
Below the code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   char * pValue = "-1234657890000";
    unsigned long ValueLong ;
    sscanf( pValue, "%llu", &ValueLong ) ;
    printf ("%llu",ValueLong);
}
```

Instead of having "-1234657890000" as printf output, the code is diplaying this value "**18446742839051661616**"
Any advise please?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is not with the code, but with your expectations. What exact *unsigned* result did you expect?

Comment: Common sense. For everything else, there is the *****Card...

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself: "convert a negative number to unsigned long". This is what happens when you convert a negative value to a positive, that is when you "tell your compiler what to do".

You operate with same internal (binary) representation of a value, same sequence of zeroes and ones. Type signed or unsigned tells the compiler how to treat memory that holds the value and is referred to by a variable.

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
       char * pValue = "-1234657890000";
       long ValueLong ;
       sscanf( pValue, "%ld", &ValueLong ) ;
       printf ("%ld\n",ValueLong);
       unsigned long v = (unsigned long)ValueLong;
       printf ("%lu\n",v);
}
```

You'll get

```
-1234657890000
18446742839051661616
```

Here is probably is a more interesting example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

main()
{
       char * pValue = "-1";
       long ValueLong ;
       sscanf( pValue, "%ld", &ValueLong ) ;
       printf ("%ld\n",ValueLong);
       unsigned long v = (unsigned long)ValueLong;
       printf ("%x\n",v);
       printf ("%x\n",UINT_MAX);
}
```

And the output is

```
-1
ffffffff
ffffffff
```

Bear in mind that output depends on the target platform

Answer (score 1):

The value you provide will not fit in unsigned long(or at least it is not guaranteed to fit). Another point is that `-1234567890000` is not at all **unsigned**. Use `long long` instead and keep in mind that the literal should be suffixed with LL like so:

```
char * pValue = "-1234657890000LL";
```

Comment: @lvaylo correct answer. You can also answer why we need to use long long. I answered(thats the problem with the range of the compiler) but I think your answer is in the right direction.

Comment: @Megharaj I believe the first and the second sentences of my answer give the reasons for that.

Answer (score 0):

Truly speaking the range of an Integer constant depends upon the compiler. For a 16-bit compiler like Turbo C or Turbo C++ the range is –32768 to 32767. For a 32-bit compiler the range would be even greater. I hope you got the answer. You are crossing the range

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all,it is solved as per your suggestions as below, the problem was on the unsigned datatype as you mention

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   char * pValue = "-1234657890000";
    long long  ValueLong ;
    sscanf( pValue, "%ld", &ValueLong ) ;
    printf ("%ld",ValueLong);
}
```

Comment: I think you want `%lld`, not `%ld`  OR use `long ValueLong`.  Recommend the first as many systems with `long` will not store "-1234657890000" correctly.